# Question about behaviour of find

Tags: find

I have trouble deciphering the man page of find and especially the part that states the order of evaluation of logical operators that link the tests. 
The man page says:

```
 OPERATORS
   Listed in order of decreasing precedence:

   ( expr )
          Force precedence. Since parentheses are special to the shell,
          you will normally need to quote them.
          Many of the examples in this manual page use backslashes
          for this purpose: `\(...\)' instead of `(...)'.

   expr1 expr2
          Two  expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an
          implied -a; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is false.

   expr1 -a expr2
          Same as expr1 expr2.

   expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.


   Please note that -a when specified implicitly (for example by two
   tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or
   explicitly has higher precedence than -o. This means that 
   find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print will never print afile.
```

So far so good:
I have compiled two programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        printf("THIS IS PGM1. I RETURN FALSE.\n");
        return 1;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        printf("THIS IS PGM2. I RETURN TRUE.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Then I have:

```
lalev@dragonfly:~/example10$ ls -l
total 32
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lalev lalev 8296 Jan 18 12:16 pgm1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lalev lalev  112 Jan 18 12:16 pgm1.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lalev lalev 8296 Jan 18 12:16 pgm2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lalev lalev  111 Jan 18 12:16 pgm2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lalev lalev    0 Jan 17 23:10 test1
lalev@dragonfly:~/example10$ find . -exec ./pgm1 \; -o -exec ./pgm2 \; -print
THIS IS PGM1. I RETURN FALSE.
THIS IS PGM2. I RETURN TRUE.
.
THIS IS PGM1. I RETURN FALSE.
THIS IS PGM2. I RETURN TRUE.
./pgm1.c
[...]
lalev@dragonfly:~/example10$
```

It seems to me that the way find evaluates logical operators differs from the description in the manpage. It goes left to right with `-o` and `-a` being of equal priority. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -exec ./pgm1 \; -o -exec ./pgm2 \; -print
       |---expr1-----|    |----expr2------------|
```

The exit code of `pgm1` is always **1**, which means expr1 is false. According to the man page `find` will evaluate expr2, which is `pgm2` in this case.

So both `pgm1` and `pgm2` was executed.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for pointing out. edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your test doesn’t demonstrate precedence differences; try

```
find . -exec ./pgm1 \; -print -o -exec ./pgm2 \;
```

to see the difference. `-a` (or no operator) binds more strongly than `-o`, so `-print` is bound to `-exec ./pgm1` and is never evaluated since `pgm1` always fails.

In your example, for every file it finds, `find` runs `pgm1`, which fails, causing `find` to evaluate the other branch of the `-o` operator, therefore running `pgm2`, which succeeds, followed by `-print`.

Comment: It may help if we clarify that the OP's is `find . \( -exec ./pgm1 \; \) -o \( -exec ./pgm2 \; -a -print \)`

Comment: Or  `find . -exec ./pgm2 \; -o -exec ./pgm1 \; -print` which might better show that the operators don't work left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize once again to see If I got it this time:
find always evaluates predicates in such fashion that it splits the command line in two - "left" and "right" part. When it decides how to split it, the operator precedence takes control and the line is split at the operator with least precedence. 
Then the left part is executed first and then eventually, the right part. And if each part has  more than two predicates, joined by logical operator, it gets executed recursively in the same fashion.

Answer (score -1):

So, basically the higher precedence of -and is not meaning it gets executed first, but it means that it gets executed last... That is "-a binds more than -o".

Comment: That's a confusing explanation at best. `-a` having a higher precedence than `-o` means that `foo -o bar -a doo` is the same as `foo -o \( bar -a doo \)`, not `\( foo -o bar \) -a doo`. (The `-a` grabs a tighter hold of the middle operand `bar` than `-o`, so to say.)